# Запрет перенаправления API Яндекс Карт

Tags: react-native, yandex-maps-jsapi

Используется Yandex Maps JS API V2.1. По умолчанию карта использует дефолтный набор управления, который включает несколько кнопок, соответственно скрыть их нельзя. При нажатии на них карта перезагружается на более новую версию API или перенаправляет на другой сайт. Некоторые другие элементы управления тоже могут перезагружать карту на более новую версию, необходимо этого избежать.

(Для контекста, карта находится в WebView контейнере React Natve)

Или, если вы знаете есть ли возможность программно добавить собственные маршруты в API V3, подскажите пожалуйста, поскольку в документации ничего не нашел